# Cassandra Schema for standard SELECT/FROM/WHERE/IN query

Tags: cassandra

Pretty new to Cassandra - I have data that looks like this:

`<geohash text, category int, payload text>`

The *only* query I want to run is:

`SELECT category, payload FROM table WHERE geohash IN (list of 9 geohashes)`

What would be the best schema in this case?

I know I could simply make my geohash the primary key and be done with it, but is there a better approach?

What are the benefits for defining `PRIMARY KEY (geohash, category, payload)`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your data for each row (geohash text, category int, payload text). If your payload size does not reach to tens of Mb, then you may want to put more **geohash** values into the same partition by using an artificial **bucketId int**, so your query can be performed on a server. Schema would look like this
**geohash text, bucketId int, category int, payload text** where the partition key is goehash and bucketId. 
The recommendation is to have a sizeable partition <= 100 Mb, so you don't have to look up too many partitions. More is available [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling).

If you have a primary key on `(geohash, category, payload)`, then you can have your data sorted on `category and payload` in the **ascending** order.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the query, it sounds like you're considering a CQL schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE geohash_data (
  geohash text,
  category int,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY (geohash)
);
```

In Cassandra, the first (and in this case only) column in your `PRIMARY KEY` is the Partition Key. The Partition Key is what's used to distribute data around the cluster. So when you do your `SELECT ... IN ()` query, you're basically querying for the data in 9 different partitions which, depending on how large your cluster is, the replication factor, and the consistency level you use to do the query, could end up querying at least *9 servers* (and maybe more). Why does that matter?

1. Latency: The more partitions (and thus replicas/servers) involved in our query, the more potential for a slow server being able to negatively impact how quickly the data is returned.
2. Availability: The more partitions (and thus replicas/servers) involved in our query, the more potential that a single server going down could make it impossible for the query to be satisfied at all.

Both of those are bad scenarios so (as Toan rightly points out in his answer and the link he provided), we try to data model in Cassandra so that our queries will hit as few partitions (and thus replicas/servers) as possible. What does that mean for your scenario? Without knowing all the details, it's hard to say for sure, but let me make a couple guesses about your scenario and give you an example of how I'd try to solve it.

It sounds like maybe you already know the list of possible `geohash` values ahead of time (maybe they're at some regularly spaced interval of a predefined grid). It also sounds like maybe you're querying for 9 geohash values because you're doing some kind of "proximity" search where you're trying to get the data for the 9 geohashes in each direction around a given point.

If that's the case, the trick could be to denormalize the data at write time into a data model optimized for reading. For example, a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE geohash_data (
  geohash text,
  data_geohash text,
  category int,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY (geohash, data_geohash)
);
```

When you `INSERT` a data point, you'd calculate the geohashes for the surrounding areas where you expect that data should show up in the results. You'd then `INSERT` the data *multiple times* for each geohash you calculated. So the value for `geohash` is the calculated value where you expect it to show up in the query results and the value for `data_geohash` is the actual value from the data you're inserting. Thus you'd have multiple (up to 9?) rows in your partition for a given `geohash` which represent the data of the surrounding geohashes.

This means your `SELECT` query now doesn't have to do an `IN` and hit multiple partitions. You just query `WHERE geohash = ?` for the point you want to search around.